# an error in ASP .NET4 + Linq

Tags: sql, asp.net, linq

I'm working on a project that using ASP .NET 4 C# (with Linq) and SQL server. All run well open page on my own computer IIS and connect to local sql database. and it is ok if connection to server database with IIS from my computer. Error happen if open published page (of cause it run from server IIS and will connect to server database). 
Error from server's event log is

> Log Name:      Application
>   Source:        ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0
>   Date:          4/17/2015 1:33:11 PM
>   Event ID:      1309
>   Task Category: Web Event
>   Level:         Warning
>   Keywords:      Classic
>   User:          N/A
>   Computer:      SZHDB1.ds.jdsu.net
>   Description:
>   Event code: 3005 
>   Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
>   Event time: 4/17/2015 1:33:11 PM 
>   Event time (UTC): 4/17/2015 5:33:11 AM 
>   Event ID: 89f5a478bff241d3aaa4798ce86ad707 
>   Event sequence: 22 
>   Event occurrence: 1 
>   Event detail code: 0
>
> Application information: 
>       Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/IMS-2-130737223782305527 
>       Trust level: Full 
>       Application Virtual Path: /IMS 
>       Application Path: D:\WebSite\IMS\ 
>       Machine name: SZHDB1
>
> Process information: 
>       Process ID: 3944 
>       Process name: w3wp.exe 
>       Account name: IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0
>
> Exception information: 
>       Exception type: UpdateException 
>       Exception message: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>      at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
>      at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
>      at Log.set_storeLog(String value) in C:\Users\che57576\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\InstrManage\InstrManage\App\Common.cs:line 26
>      at InstrManage.Admin.Group.GridView_group_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\che57576\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\InstrManage\InstrManage\Admin\Group.aspx.cs:line 164
>      at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>
> String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
>      at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)

and the related code are here:
'Common.cs':

```
public class Log
{
string conn, username;
public string storeLog
{
    set
    {
        using (AdminEntities myEntrities = new AdminEntities(conn))
        {
            IMSlog log = new IMSlog();
            log.user_name = username;
            log.date_time = DateTimeOffset.Now;
            log.what = value;
            myEntrities.IMSlogs.AddObject(log);
            myEntrities.SaveChanges();    //this is line 26
        }
    }
}
public Log(string linqConn,string userName)
{
    conn = linqConn;
    username = userName;
}
}
```

'Group.aspx.cs':

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            log = new Log(sqlconnstr, Session["UserName"].ToString());

    }
```

and in the same page, in the event:

```
protected void GridView_group_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool result;
        result = Int32.TryParse(GridView_group.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text.ToString(), out index);
        currentStatus = (GridView_group.SelectedRow.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox).Checked;
            using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                using (AdminEntities myEntrities = new AdminEntities(sqlconnstr))
                {
                    admin_group c = (from r in myEntrities.admin_group
                                     where r.group_id == index
                                     select r).First();
                    c.group_enable = !currentStatus;
                    myEntrities.SaveChanges();

                    log.storeLog = "Set group ID " + index.ToString() + " to    " + Convert.ToString(!currentStatus);    // this is line 164

                }
                scope.Complete(); //  To commit.

            }

            queryGroup();
    }
```

when the above event be trigger, the error will happen.

I've search from lots of time, not sure why my laptop is ok but server cannot.
my laptop is win7 and sql express.
server is asp .net 4 and SQL server 2008.

Comment: *"String or binary data would be truncated"* is the root cause - your data exceeds the column length and is rejected by your database.

Comment: Hi Filburt,thanks for you reply. I just checked my column design. log_id is bigint. datatime is datatimeoffset(0). user name is nchar(10), and log.what is ntext. those should big enough for my current using. The strange is my computer IIS + server database is ok. But server IIS + server database has that issue. all with same operations.

Comment: I'd recommend to directly check your sql server query log to see what values are about to be sent for update.

Comment: Hi Filburt, with your guide, I found the root cause. the user name should lees than 10 but for some reason it gets wrong value and exceed that number so error happen. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are trying to save a value too long for the length available in the database.

To find the problem, try to look at the length of the username you are trying to save and compare it to what's available in the database.

By setting a breakpoint on row #26 in Common.cs, you should be able to see the content of the variable username.

Once you find the problem, you can increase the size in your database. Also, it's recommended to validate the length of your username directly in your Web Application so the user can't enter a username too long for your database, an error message should be sent to the user asking him to use a shorter username.

Answer (score 0):

One of the following assignments is too large for your data store

```
log.user_name = username;
log.date_time = DateTimeOffset.Now;
log.what = value;
```

You can also check if `log.date_time` is assigned the correct value

Comment: your are right, my problem is user name gets wrong strings and exceed. i create a temp table with with large room for this column and catch this. thanks!